# Tawkto display position fixing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using tawkto to chat with visitor. It displays when my page loaded. I want to make visible when visitor scroll to bottom. Is it possible?

Comment: Please post some code. Your question it to vague.

Comment: Using this https://www.tawk.to/

Comment: I understand what you are using, but I do not understand what you are trying to do. Post the code of your page where you have this installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Make the chat div to display:none and then use the script.

```
 <style>
   #tawkchat-iframe-container{
     display: none !important;
   }
 </style>

<script>
 $("body").scroll(function(){
   $("#tawkchat-iframe-container").show();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: rought styles cant change the element style that is placed by JS. You need to reset the styles of the target before you  add new styles.

Answer (score 0):

close your elements in a div like

```
<div id="chatbox">
   <!-- whatever here-->
</div>
```

then style it

```
    #chatbox {
               position: fixed;
               bottom: 0; right: 0;
              }
```

and make sure the div is direct child of `<body>` element